# How to check raw_input answers inside if-statements

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, raw-input

I'm sorry as this is probably a dumb question, but I'm just beginning to learn to code Python and I'm trying to make a game that checks certain inputs from the users.  The script, however, is not accepting the correct answer and running the next function.

```
def left2():
    x = 5 + 5  


def left():
    x = raw_input("What is Dwyane's last name?")  
    x = x.lower # changes to the lowercase version of the name 

    if x == 'johnson':  # Code stopping here, It's not recognizing the input
        left2()
    elif x == "":
        left2()
    else:
        print "You're lost!" # This is displayed regardless of what I type
```

Comment: `x = x.lower()`, That is the correct way of calling the method onto a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's running now

Comment: You can also just call lower on raw_input

Comment: There are some answers below explaining this in some detail, read those as well @CodeZilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the second line of `left()` which should read:

```
x = x.lower() # changes to the lowercase version of the name
```

The parentheses call the `lower` method on `x` and reassign what that returns to `x`, rather than just setting `x` to the callable method itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning x to a function object, not to the string returned as result.

code should be:

```
x = x.lower()
```